# wordpress in apache just work on localhost and not working in another local computers

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I installed Apache on one of my computers so that I can easily access my site by typing the IP of any system, but Apache easily shows the index.hml file and the phpmyadmin subdomain, but when I copy WordPress, it shows the following error gives:

in chrome in another pc:

(This site can’t be reached
www.risemisse.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN)

and in localhost:
easily show my wordpress site

and then i copy files and directory in html directory and it show me simillar error:
in html directory :[image]

in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

i added in ports.cnf: LISTEN 8080

and in /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       mohamamdjavad-pc

# I aded this
127.0.0.1 risemisse.com
127.0.0.1 www.risemisse.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

ufw :

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80 on enp1s0               ALLOW       Anywhere                  
24800                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6) on enp1s0          ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
24800 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Thank you for helping me to use the Apache computer on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

It was correct when I entered ***my IP*** into these **( settings > general > WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address(URL) )**